# Flowchart nested for-loop

Tags: python, flowchart, python-turtle, nested-for-loop

I have this code and I tried to do a flowchart but I have no clue how to make one.
All of my Flowchart I made, don't make any sense.

Could anyone of you guys please help me out???

```
import turtle

STARTING_X, STARTING_Y = 350, 200

turtle.penup()
turtle.width(2)
turtle.setheading(180)
turtle.sety(STARTING_Y)

for a in range(1, 8):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setx(STARTING_X)

    for b in range(a):
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.circle(25)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.forward(60)

    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - 60)

turtle.done()
```

Comment: What figure / drawing would you like to achieve?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you, but the program code I posted is correct. So I have to make a flowchart to that code.

Comment: Oh you just want to know how the code works? Or am I missing something

Comment: yeah kinda. I know a bit how it works, but I cannot put it into a flowchart. I don't know which conditions, statements etc.

Comment: I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
# part 1
import turtle
STARTING_X, STARTING_Y = 350, 200
turtle.penup()
turtle.width(2)
turtle.setheading(180)
turtle.sety(STARTING_Y)

# part 2
for a in range(1, 8):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setx(STARTING_X)

    for b in range(a):    # part 3
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.circle(25)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.forward(60)

    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - 60)

turtle.done()
```

**Part 1:**

- Importing turtle
- Making global variables for starting positions
- turtle stuff (read docs)

**Part 2:**

- for loop that runs 8 times
- turtle pen up (not drawing)
- start at predefined x position
- for loop (see Part 3)
- lower the y position with 60

**Part 3:**

- runs `a` times
- turtle pendown (drawing)
- drawing a circle
- turtle penup (not drawing)
- go forward with 60 (in this case, lower the x position with 60 because of the direction in part 1)

**Summary**
This program draws 8 lines of circles, and each nth line contains n circles aligned to the right like this:

```
        *
       **  
      *** 
     **** 
    ***** 
   ****** 
  ******* 
 ********
```

But circles instead of stars

Comment: appreciated Seppukki

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you very much for your help :)

But my question now is how to put that information into a flowchart like this.
I mean what's the Condition 1 / 2, what are the statements etc.

[image]

Comment: Condition 1: a < 8 ( first for loop )
Condition 2: b < a ( second for loop) = simple version.
This is not what's really happening, instead the range(x,y) generates a list from x to y-1 and a / b cycles through that list

Comment: so you're saying that I could use this simple version and it's correct or am I wrong.

Comment: Sorry if it's too obvious. I am new at pragramming.

Comment: You can always try some thing out to learn how they work. e.g. `for i in range(1,8)` is very similar to `while i < 8`

Comment: you can try both with `print(i)` as the body